# In R, how to replace values in specific rows with those from another row, based on a condition?

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have data from a randomized controlled trial. The data is in wide format.

Some of the participants in my dataset required a special interim measurement in between the usual time 1 and time 2 measurements. Thus, like IDs 1 and 3 below, those individuals all have an extra row corresponding to that extra measurement (which I call t1.5 below).

For those participants, I need the t1.5 measurement to replace the t1 measurement. So, for the example dataset below, for ID #1, I would like t1 OUTCOME to be 48, and for ID #3, t1 OUTCOME should be 44. It's fine to fully overwrite and ignore the original t1 values for those we're replacing, and after that I can also remove all the t1.5 rows completely.

Example data:

```r
tibble::tribble(~ ID, ~TIME, ~OUTCOME, 1, "t1", 50, 1, "t1.5", 48, 1, "t2", 
    30, 2, "t1" ,31 ,2, "t2", 20, 3, "t1", 45, 3, "t1.5", 44, 3, "t2", 33)

ID  TIME       OUTCOME
1   t1         50
1   t1.5       48
1   t2         30
2   t1         31
2   t2         20
3   t1         45
3   t1.5       44
3   t2         33
```

I am using R 4.2. I can brute force it, but I'm sure there's a way to do it elegantly. I'd love a solution using tidyverse (dplyr, tidyr, or what have you) syntax.

I already have a numeric vector `pesky_IDs` which lists all IDs needing replacement. I thought it could be useful to utilize `ID %in% pesky_IDs` ...but in which function? (Or just ignore this last point and show me the better way!)

Thanks all - I am continuously impressed by this community!

I honestly am not sure where to start without doing something verbose and inelegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(OUTCOME = replace(OUTCOME, TIME == 't1' & 't1.5'%in%TIME, 
                            OUTCOME[TIME == 't1.5']))

# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID TIME  OUTCOME
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     1 t1         48
2     1 t1.5       48
3     1 t2         30
4     2 t1         31
5     2 t2         20
6     3 t1         44
7     3 t1.5       44
8     3 t2         33
```